# How do I ignore hidden files (and files in hidden directories) with Boost Filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem, hidden-files

I am iterating through all files in a directory recursively using the following:

```
try
{
    for ( bf::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir("./");
          dir != end; ++dir )
    {
       const bf::path &p = dir->path();
       if(bf::is_regular_file(p))
       {
           std::cout << "File found: " << p.string() << std::endl;
       }
    }
} catch (const bf::filesystem_error& ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
}
```

But this includes hidden files and files in hidden directories.

How do I filter out these files?  If needed I can limit myself to platforms where hidden files and directories begin with the '.' character.

Comment: That works for hidden files, but what about excluding all the non-hidden files present in a hidden subdirectory such as ".svn"?  I think I need to check every component of the path for an initial "." or something like that (also properly handling "../" components, etc). I'd rather use something cross platform if it exists in Boost, although I wasn't able to find it in the docs.

Comment: What do you define as a "hidden file"?

Comment: @Code-Guru Good question! If there's a nice cross-platform definition I'll use that, provided it does the right thing on Unix-like platforms (files/directories beginning with "." are hidden).  Maybe there's no good way to abstract over the various notions of hidden. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) has a reasonable description of what "hidden" means on common platforms.  For now I only care about Unix-like platforms, but I like to keep things cross-platform where I can.

Comment: @Soverman: (.svn:) if everything is hidden there, why do you traverse it? :/

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Only because I hadn't figured out how to skip it with dir.no_push() yet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a cross-platform way of handling "hidden".  The following works on Unix-like platforms:

First define:

```
bool isHidden(const bf::path &p)
{
    bf::path::string_type name = p.filename();
    if(name != ".." &&
       name != "."  &&
       name[0] == '.')
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then traversing the files becomes:

```
try
{
    for ( bf::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir("./");
           dir != end; ++dir)
    {
       const bf::path &p = dir->path();

       //Hidden directory, don't recurse into it
       if(bf::is_directory(p) && isHidden(p))
       {
           dir.no_push();
           continue;
       }

       if(bf::is_regular_file(p) && !isHidden(p))
       {
           std::cout << "File found: " << p.string() << std::endl;
       }
    }
} catch (const bf::filesystem_error& ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Now that you have a working answer, you may want to optimize it. It seems to me that you do a lot of extra work by visiting files in a "hidden" directory. If you can find a way to *not* visit the files inside that directory, you wouldn't need to check the full path of each file.

Comment: if(name != ".." && name != "."  && name[0] == '.'). What if name.empty() == true ? i suggest if(name != ".." && name != "."  && name.length() > 1 && name[0] == '.')

Comment: @kwirz I've never run in to a file system that allowed empty strings for naming directories or files.  Have you seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for now that you want to ignore files which start with a `'.'`. This is the standard indication in Unix for a hidden file. I suggest writing a recursive function to visit each file. In pseudocode, it looks something like this:

```
visitDirectory dir
    for each file in dir
        if the filename of file does not begin with a '.'
            if file is a directory
                visitDirectory file
            else
                do something with file (perhas as a separate function call?)
```

This avoids the need to search the whole path of a file to determine whether or not we want to deal with it. Instead, we simply skip any directories which are "hidden."

I can think of several iterative solutions as well, if that's what you prefer. One is to have a stack or queue to keep track of which directory to visit next. Basically this emulates the recursive version with your own data structure. Alternatively, if you are stuck on parsing the full path of the file, simply make sure you get the absolute path. This will guarantee that you don't encounter a directory with a name like './' or '../', which would cause problems with checking for a hidden file.